# Vim, delete to row n

Tags: vim, gvim

I'm often editing files where i have to delete everything except the five first and the three last rows. I do that by moving to row six and type ":,.$-3 d". Is there any way accomplish the same using d and some kind of motion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure is!  `d[num]G` where `[num]` is the destination line number.  Any other movement command will also work rather than `G`, of course.

To delete the first five and last three rows, assuming you've just opened the file and are on the first line, it would be:

```
d5G   # delete from current position to line 5
G     # jump to last line
d2k   # delete from current position to 2 lines up (3 lines total)
```

**Edit:**  Just reread the question and saw I got your intentions backwards - you want to keep the first five/last three, not delete them.  In that case, it's:

```
G     # jump to last line
3k    # up 3 lines
d6G   # delete from current position to line 6
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I always tried to do it the other way around, positioning myself at the sixth row trying to move(delete) to row $-3.